# How to send an checkbox data as an array to a php script via jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have few checkbox like this,

```
<input type='checkbox' name='name[]' value='1' />
<input type='checkbox' name='name[]' value='2' />
<input type='checkbox' name='name[]' value='3' />
<input type='checkbox' name='name[]' value='4' />
<input type='checkbox' name='name[]' value='5' />
```

And my php processing code is below,

```
<?php
$check=$_POST['name'];

foreach($check as $arr){
//code for saving data in database
}
```

My problem is, I am trying to send the check box data via jquery/ajax. But I could not send those data to the php page as an array.

Please tell me I could I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/) the checkboxes and send them to PHP :

```
$.ajax({
    url  : 'processing.php',
    data : $('[name="name[]"]').serialize()
}).done(function(result) {
    // ta da
});
```

Note that only checked boxes will be serialized, as there is generally no need to do anything for unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

View

```
        <input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='1' />
        <input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='2' />
        <input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='3' />
        <input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='4' />
        <input type='checkbox' name='name[]' class="checkBoxGroup" value='5' />
```

Script

```
        $ary=$(".checkBoxGroup").serializeArray();
        alert($ary[0]['value']);
```